# DAX number format with a plus or minus sign

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to format DAX measure so that value `0.105` is displayed as `+10.5%`, and value `-0.105` is displayed as `-10.5%`. Important for me is the plus sign. I failed using `FORMAT(measure, "+0.0%")`.

I cannot find anything helpful in `FORMAT` function doc:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function

The only solution I can think of is handling it with `IF` or `SWITCH` function. Is there a way to avoid it?

```
IF(variable>0, "+"&variable, variable)
```

Comment: FORMAT(measure, "+0.0%") works perfectly fine for me in PowerBI. What exactly failed for you?

Comment: Have you tried negative values? With `FORMAT(measure, "+0.0%")` I get `+-10.5%`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to create custom format for both positive  and negative numbers:

```
Formatted Value = FORMAT( [Measure], "+0.0%;-0.0%")
```

Result:
[image]

In general, custom format string consists of 4 parts, separated by ;

```
Positive values; Negative values; Zero values; Text values
```

One section is required, others are optional. So, to avoid + in front of zero, a full code might be:

```
Formatted Value = FORMAT( [Measure], "+0.0%;-0.0%;"0")
```

Comment: Where did you get that from? Can you link to documentation in your answer? I mean 4 arguments for custom format.

Comment: Format is DAX uses regular Excel custom formating rules. I know them by heart, but google "Excel custom formats"

Comment: your solution has a bug. If the [measure]=-0.001 (notice minus), then FORMAT( [Measure], "+0.0%;-0.0%) returns +0.0% which is wrong. Desired results would be -0.0%. Imagine you have absolute value of say -123 (drop) and percentage value, which is displayed by our measure and the result +0.0% would be of different sign.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. My model shows -0.1%

Comment: Sorry [measure]=-0.00001 Get it more tiny please.

Comment: Ok, I see. It's not a bug, it's the way Microsoft designed formatting in all their applications. Any number that has more digits than format pattern allows, is automatically rounded. So, your -0.00001 becomes 0. Since you don't have custom code for zero, it shows default pattern (for positive numbers). If you want to see -0.00001 as a negative number, increase the format precision, i.e. : -0.000% . To prevent such problems, round your measure to the fixed number of digits that matches custom format precision.

Comment: Yes, but that is not tidy. I use combination of your suggestion with SWITCH(TRUE,...

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the game perhaps. And yes, formatting negative numbers in parentheses  was a bit difficult in Power BI before. As other answers suggest, it would involve the FORMAT function. But today you can use custom formatting for a measure. For example "#,##0.0, (#.##0.0)". Hope that helps. You can find a more elaborate explanation here:

[Format Negative values between Parentheses](https://gorilla.bi/power-bi/display-negative-numbers-between-parentheses/)

Keep crushing it!

Rick

Answer (score 0):

I keep RADO's answer as accepted. I ended up with solution, which overcomes the problem of very small negative fractional values - for example value of `-0.0001` which may become positive zero after rounding by `FORMAT` function (see discussion in our comments).

```
Plus Minus Growth =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    ISBLANK ( [Growth] ), BLANK (),
    [Growth] >= 0, FORMAT ( [Growth], "+0.0 % ▲;-0.0 % ▼" ), -- positive here
    [Growth] <  0, FORMAT ( [Growth], "-0.0 % ▼;-0.0 % ▼" ), -- negative here
    BLANK ()
)
```

Negative fractional numbers which are rounded to positive zero by `FORMAT` function fall in the first part of the code `"-0.0 % ▼;-0.0 % ▼"`